# how to resolve findviewbyid in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried almost everything but it doesn't seem to work, I keep getting a cannot resolve findviewById for the buttons at the bottom. the button declarations have the same errors but I have fixed those correctly, the bottom buttons don't seem to behave the same way. I'm new to android, please help!

[image: 1]

Comment: Please add code.

Comment: You should add code rather than a picture. It will help to understand what the actual problem is

Comment: Where is this code? Is it in a Fragment or Activity? Please add a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `requireActivity()` before findViewById. for example:

```
btn = requireActivity().findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)
```